Permission deniedと出て実行ファイルを実行できない
ラズベリーパイでのpermission deniedを解決したいです。
プログラミング初心者です。ラズベリーパイでHelloWorldを表示するプログラムを作成してコンパイルとビルドを行い実行しようしたところ、
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ gcc -Wall -o hello hello.c
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ ./hello
bash: ./hello: 許可がありません

とメッセージが出力されて実行できませんでした。一体なぜなのか教えてください。
ちなみに、ファイルはOSが入っていない外部メモリの中(マイクロSDカード32GB)にあり、使用前にRaspberry Pi Imager(v1.9.1)でカードをFAT32でフォーマットしてあります。
環境
ラズパイ：Raspberry Pi 5 8GB
OS
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

OSは64bit対応です。
カーネル
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.6.51+rpt-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 (2024-10-08) aarch64 GNU/Linux

やってみたこと

ls -lで権限を確認し、chmodで権限の変更をしてみた

moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ ls -l
合計 96
-rw-r--r-- 1 moyashi moyashi 70432 11月 26 19:52 hello
-rw-r--r-- 1 moyashi moyashi   909 11月 26 18:42 hello.c
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ chmod 755 hello
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ ls -l
合計 96
-rw-r--r-- 1 moyashi moyashi 70432 11月 26 19:52 hello
-rw-r--r-- 1 moyashi moyashi   909 11月 26 18:42 hello.c
moyashi@raspberrypi:/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/programming/C $ 

chmodで権限の変更をしているはずですが、なぜか変更できませんでした。(ちなみにOSのあるメモリ内の権限の変更はできました。)

ファイルhelloのディレクトリを変更してみた
ファイルをOSのあるメモリ内のホームフォルダ内に移動させ、権限を変更し実行しました。

moyashi@raspberrypi:~ $ chmod 755 hello
moyashi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l
合計 108
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 19 22:36 Bookshelf
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 Desktop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 moyashi moyashi 70432 11月 26 19:52 hello
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 25 00:32 ダウンロード
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 テンプレート
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 ドキュメント
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 ビデオ
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 音楽
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 画像
drwxr-xr-x 2 moyashi moyashi  4096 11月 24 11:40 公開
moyashi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./hello
HelloWorld!

実行と権限の変更ができました。しかし、このOSに入っているメモリの残り容量がほとんどないのでできればOSが入っていない方のメモリで実行したいです。
使用したコード
hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("HelloWorld!\n");
    
    return 0;
}

文章がわかりにくく長くなって申し訳ありません。

UNIX系のファイルシステムではchmodなどを利用して
ファイルやディレクトリのアクセス権(パーミッション)を変更できます
Linuxでは ext4 などがよく使われます
参考:

(archlinux.jp) ファイルシステム
ファイルのパーミッションと属性

それらのオーナーID(UID) グループ(GID), 各種属性ビットがファイルシステムに存在しないと(管理情報持っていないと), それらを利用することはできません
/media/moyashi/78C8-A230/ というのは USBメモリーのようなもので多分 FATだと思われます
そのままでは実行権限など付けることはできないので, 一度ローカル(の ext4 など)にコピーし
作業を行うとよいかもしれません

USBメモリーでどうしても作業行うなら, ext2でフォーマットし利用するという手も有るかも
例えば Windowsでも利用するなら Ext2Fsd などか使えるようです
※ ただし抜き差しできるメディアで実行権限与える場合, 何らかの操作が必要になるはず
